# How to get category id of lineItem to use in commerce adjuster

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, adjusters

I want to add an adjustment to a product in the basket via an adjuster,
only when the product has certain categories.
(10% off if there are more than 6 same items in the basket. It's not possible to do this via the backend of commerce right now, unless I do it for every single product. But there are so many and want to do it once and for all).

I put a light switch on the categories. If the light switch is on, I want to compare the categories of the lineItem in the basket to the categories where the discount can be applied for.

So far I have the categories with which there is a discount possible in an array ($allowedCategoryIds), but I have trouble of getting the categories ID of a lineItem.
(-> $categoryIds).

```
foreach ($order->lineItems as $lineItem) {

        // Get the categories associated with the line Item
        $categories = $lineItem->getProductType()->getCategories();

        // Loop through the categories and get their IDs
        $categoryIds = [];
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
          $categoryIds[] = $category->id;
        }
        
        if (in_array($categoryIds, $allowedCategoryIds)) {

// apply the adjustment code //
}
```

**EDIT**

i changed my plan and put a lightswitch on a product, deciding if the product can be get the discount adjusment or not.
in my adjuster i checked if the lightswitch is set or not.
For me its more futureproof, as there could be more categories on a product, which might interfere each other (as one can have a discount and the other one not)

```
if ($lineItem->lightSwitchHandle) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the related categories from the product type. I think you want to get the category IDs from the relationship field on the variant or purchasable:

```php
if($purchasable = $lineItem->getPurchasable())
{
    if($purchasable instanceof Variant){
        $categoryIdsRelatedToVariant = $purchasable->categoryRelationFieldNameHere->ids();
        $categoryIdsRelatedToProduct = $purchasable->getProduct()->categoryRelationFieldNameHere->ids();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try that out later. I have different category relation fields (some product have these, some these). I do have to do that then for every category relation field and then combine these together, right?

Comment: Cannot get it working. If i Craft::dd($purchasable); or lineItem, the Category Field is always null. categoryRelationFieldNameHere should be the fieldhandle of the category field?
I tried also to get the field like this, but no luck:

$catDeliField = Craft::$app->getFields()>getFieldByHandle('categoryFieldHandle');

$catFieldFieldColumn = ElementHelper::fieldColumnFromField($catDeliField);